# http://example.com/main.php?add=

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to create a php script where I am able able to do

> http://example.com/main.php?add=[$id + 1]

It connects to a mysql database.
$id is an integer, lets just say the value is 1 (just to be an example).
I want it to gather the $id from a mysql table called scriptid. (column 0)
I want it to select the column from a mysql table called scriptlist.
I want the column number to be the value of $id + 1,
e.g http://example.com/main.php?add=2.
When it does 'add' it will change the value of the column entered ($id + 1) to 1.

So far I have this, I am new to both php and mysql and am very confused, even after reading loads of guides.

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM scriptlist");
$rowlist = mysql_fetch_row($check);
if($rowlist) {
mysql_query("UPDATE scriptlist SET user = 'dan' WHERE " . $rowlist['$id'] + 1 . " =     '1'"); 
echo($rowlist['$id'] + 1 . " = '1'");
}
```

I don't think my code will actually help you understand it more, but yeah.

Comment: Posting the table structure certainly would help.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_` functions and print your query before executing it, you'll see what goes wrong.

Comment: The title of this question is just awful, consider rephrasing your question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sur of what you ask but maybe it's what you're looking for:

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM scriptlist");
$rowlist = mysql_fetch_row($check);
if($rowlist) {
mysql_query("UPDATE scriptlist SET user = 'dan' WHERE " . $rowlist[$id + 1]. " =     '1'"); 
echo($rowlist[$id + 1] . " = '1'");
}
```